# I'm beginner in php and I don't understand what is means the 'cid='

Tags: php

I'm beginner in php and I don't understand what is means  the 'cid=' ,
for example I have a php page 'view_category.php'
and I saw in youtube video that he expalined to write
`<a href='view_category.php?cid="$id."`

I don't understand how this working? how this page create? 
I just create view_category, so how it possible to see another pages with difference id.

Comment: it's called a GET parameter; look at up. Btw, `cID` and `cid` are two different animals.

Comment: [The manual should be your first port of call](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) not SO

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know what si GET parameter but I do not understand how it works. for me it looks like create dynamic website with the cid, am I right?

Comment: I would say you are right and is either related to pagination or querying a database.

Comment: Pass values to the same or different page using the url (query strings). Should only be used for routing / pagination /custom db queries. No sensitive data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'cid=' is not a constant in PHP it can be any value even your name or any name. They are referred to as **url parameters**.  The value of the url parameter can be fetched using [$_GET[''] method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

When you click the link `"<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."'> link </a>"` Then a the browser will open a page with a url looking like

```
www.domain.com?cid=5
```

Then using php you may get the value of url parameter **cid**

```
$valueofparameter = $_GET['cid'];
```

Comment: i understand, but the problem is how it create a new url link? where is host? I only open and save 'view_category.php' file in my host.

Comment: view_category.php is just a page. and when you click the link with the url parameter then the url may look like `view_category.php?cid=5` may be the cid means category id. Therefore the page is going to view items with foreign key of category_id of 5... depending on your MySQL query. or any of the value on the url parameter.

Comment: the **$id** in the `...cid=$id...` is a variable learn more on variables. they are more useful more so when the values are dynamic http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

Comment: i know about variables. but as I said before I'm not really understand how it happends. because cid isn't variable in MYSQL so how I can write 'view_category.php?cid=5' and to see this page?